# perl -lane change delimiter

Tags: perl, one-liner

I have one liner:

```
az account list  -o table |perl -lane 'print $F[0] if /GS/i'
```

I want to change default delimiter from '\t' to '-'

Any hint how to do this?

Just wanted to stress that it is oneliner I look for ;)

Answer (score 7):

Plain `-a` splits on any whitespace, not just tab. The `-F` option allows you to specify a different delimiter.

```
az account list  -o table |
perl -laF- -ne 'print $F[0] if /GS/i'
```

Answer (score 0):

[perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun) is the manual page that tells you about Perl's command-line options. It says:

> **-a**
>
> turns on autosplit mode when used with a "-n" or "-p". An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the "-n" or "-p".
>
> ```
> perl -ane 'print pop(@F), "\n";'
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
>     @F = split(' ');
>     print pop(@F), "\n";
> }
> ```
>
> An alternate delimiter may be specified using -F.

And:

> **-Fpattern**
>
> specifies the pattern to split on for "-a". The pattern may be surrounded by `//`, `""`, or `''`, otherwise it will be put in single quotes. You can't use literal whitespace or NUL characters in the pattern.
>
> -F implicitly sets both "-a" and "-n".